# Copy range of cells including border formatting x number of times

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet which contains rows of information which include borders. My information is in rows 1 to 3 on sheet2. I would like to make a macro to copy this information onto sheet3 and paste it into row1 on sheet3 then into row4 on sheet3 then in row8 on sheet2 and then do the same further down the sheet and copy it over and over again until I have the correct amount of copies that I have specified in a cell C5 on sheet1. So if I have **x** in a cell C5 on sheet1 I would like to be able to paste the row of information including boarders onto sheet3 **x** times. I have a basic understanding of VBA and have looked at other examples but cannot work out how to do this and retain the borders.

I hope this is an explanation that makes sense. Is this possible?

Thanks Greg

Comment: It's possible. AFAIK, you would need to do `.Copy` and `.Paste` or `.PasteSpecial` methods. If someone knows another way, I'd be glad to hear it too.

Comment: Do you have a pattern/order on what sheets/which row the data is to be copied? You have mentioned "`row1` on `sheet3` then into `row4` on `sheet3` then in `row8` on `sheet2` and then do the same further down the sheet and further copy it over".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Notes:

- Change copy area on Sheet 2: FIRST_ROW, FIRST_COL, TOTAL_ROWS, and TOTAL_COLS
- Cell C5 is expected to be on Sheet 1
- Sheet 3 will be deleted every time you run this macro
- It's hard to read to keep it shorter, but I can provide details if interested

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyRange()
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 1:    Const TOTAL_ROWS As Long = 3
    Const FIRST_COL As Long = 1:    Const TOTAL_COLS As Long = 3

    Dim totalCopies As Long, i As Long, sh As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.Delete
    totalCopies = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C5").Value2

    With Sheets("Sheet2")           'COPY
        .Range( _
                    .Cells(FIRST_ROW, FIRST_COL), _
                    .Cells(FIRST_ROW + TOTAL_ROWS - 1, TOTAL_COLS) _
        ).Copy
    End With

    For i = 1 To totalCopies        'PASTE * value in C5
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(((TOTAL_ROWS + 1) * (i - 1)) + 1, FIRST_COL).PasteSpecial
    Next

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Paul. I will look at this over the next day or so to understand what the code is doing and get back to you some questions to enable me to understand the coding, a big thankyou.